# How to find file which have not specific content?

Tags: ssh, files, grep, search

I have a lot of files which already have SPF records defined

```
grep -i v=spf *.db
```

**/var/named/domain.com.db**

```
domain.com.  14400   IN      TXT     "v=spf1 +a +mx +ip4:XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX ?all"
```

And want to find all files without SPF records. Some hints?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GNU grep has the `-L` option, the inverse of `-l`. It lists files with no matches. So you can do

```
grep -iL v=spf *.db
```

With a more traditional grep, you can do a `-c` count and then select the ones that have a count of 0 matches:

```
grep -ic v=spf *.db | grep ':0$' | sed 's/:0$//'
```